# Is it possible to set empty nodes to a default value in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPath, and I was wondering if it was possible to set nodes that did not exist to some default value, like "NULL".

I have an XML document and I'm trying to retrieve names for a staff listing. For example, information such as 'department', 'name', 'email', etc.  I'm throwing them into an excel spreadsheet, and I'm using the =ImportXML() function.

The problem is that everything is under the parent node 'staff' for each entry, and when I import the data for something like 'department', or 'name', or 'email', I have varying counts for column lengths.  Is it possible to retrieve every node entry and if the node does not exist, set the value in the row to something like 'null' or 'not available'?

Right Now I can retrieve the data, but it doesn't sync along the rows because of the missing data throughout the XML document.  I read something about the Becker method, but I don't completely understand.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a node to null you could ignore this and don't give it to the XML tree. So is visible which fields contains values and which not.

A null value or something similar doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm trying to set a value to NULL rather than have it skip over to the next entry, if the node does not exist.